# adding stuff to a jquery listbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am using this demo:

```
http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/v20/niceforms.html
```

i would like to know how to be able to add a datasource to this list:

```
<select size="4" name="languages[]" id="languages" multiple="multiple">

                    <option value="English">English</option>

                    <option value="French">French</option>

                    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>

                    <option value="Italian">Italian</option>

                    <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>

                    <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>

                    <option value="Russian">Russian</option>

                    <option value="Esperanto">Esperanto</option>

                </select>
```

i dont want to hard code the list i want to be able to attach it to a database or at least have a file from which it grabs these values. how would i do this? even something from the web.config file will do! thanks so much for any suggestions

jasper here is the complete code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>Niceforms</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


    <link href="niceforms/niceforms-default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="niceforms/niceforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>$(function () {
    $.get('file.txt', function (data) {
        var output = data.split(','),
            tmp = '';
        for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            tmp += '<option value=' + output[i] + '>' + output[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#languages').html(tmp);
    });
});
</script>
</head>



<body><div id="container">

<form action="vars.php" method="post" class="niceform">

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Personal Info</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="email">Email Address:</label></dt>

            <dd><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="32" maxlength="128" /></dd>

        </dl>
        </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Info</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="email">Email Address:</label></dt>

            <dd><input type="text" name="email" id="Text13" size="32" maxlength="128" /></dd>

        </dl>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="email">Email Address:</label></dt>

            <dd><input type="text" name="email" id="Text12" size="32" maxlength="128" /></dd>

        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="password">Password:</label></dt>

            <dd><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="32" maxlength="32" /></dd>

        </dl>


        <dl>

            <dt><label for="gender">Gender:</label></dt>

            <dd>

                <select size="1" name="gender" id="gender">

                    <option value="Guy">Guy</option>

                    <option value="Girl">Girl</option>

                    <option value="Dude">Dude</option>

                    <option value="Chic">Chic</option>
                    <option value="Gentleman">Gentleman</option>

                    <option value="Lady">Lady</option>

                    <option value="Male">Male</option>

                    <option value="Female">Female</option>

                    <option value="Don't Ask">Don't Ask</option>

                </select>

            </dd>

        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="dobMonth">Date of Birth:</label></dt>

            <dd>

                <select size="1" name="dobMonth" id="dobMonth">

                    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>

                    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>

                    <option value="Mar">Mar</option>

                    <option value="Apr">Apr</option>

                    <option value="May">May</option>

                    <option value="Jun">Jun</option>

                    <option value="Jul">Jul</option>

                    <option value="Aug">Aug</option>

                    <option value="Sep">Sep</option>

                    <option value="Oct">Oct</option>

                    <option value="Nov">Nov</option>

                    <option value="Dec">Dec</option>

                </select>

                <select size="1" name="dobDay" id="dobDay">

                    <option value="01">01</option>

                    <option value="02">02</option>

                    <option value="03">03</option>

                    <option value="04">04</option>

                    <option value="05">05</option>

                    <option value="06">06</option>

                    <option value="07">07</option>

                    <option value="08">08</option>

                    <option value="09">09</option>

                    <option value="10">10</option>

                    <option value="11">11</option>

                    <option value="12">12</option>

                    <option value="13">13</option>

                    <option value="14">14</option>

                    <option value="15">15</option>

                    <option value="16">16</option>

                    <option value="17">17</option>

                    <option value="18">18</option>

                    <option value="19">19</option>

                    <option value="20">20</option>

                    <option value="21">21</option>

                    <option value="22">22</option>

                    <option value="23">23</option>

                    <option value="24">24</option>

                    <option value="25">25</option>

                    <option value="26">26</option>

                    <option value="27">27</option>

                    <option value="28">28</option>

                    <option value="29">29</option>

                    <option value="30">30</option>

                    <option value="31">31</option>

                </select>

                <select size="1" name="dobYear" id="dobYear">

                    <option value="2000">2000</option>

                    <option value="1999">1999</option>

                    <option value="1998">1998</option>

                    <option value="1997">1997</option>

                    <option value="1996">1996</option>

                    <option value="1995">1995</option>

                    <option value="1994">1994</option>

                    <option value="1993">1993</option>

                    <option value="1992">1992</option>

                    <option value="1991">1991</option>

                    <option value="1990">1990</option>

                    <option value="1989">1989</option>

                    <option value="1988">1988</option>

                    <option value="1987">1987</option>

                    <option value="1986">1986</option>

                    <option value="1985">1985</option>

                    <option value="1984">1984</option>

                    <option value="1983">1983</option>

                    <option value="1982">1982</option>

                    <option value="1981">1981</option>

                    <option value="1980">1980</option>

                    <option value="1979">1979</option>

                    <option value="1978">1978</option>

                    <option value="1977">1977</option>

                    <option value="1976">1976</option>

                    <option value="1975">1975</option>

                    <option value="1974">1974</option>

                    <option value="1973">1973</option>

                    <option value="1972">1972</option>

                    <option value="1971">1971</option>

                    <option value="1970">1970</option>

                    <option value="1969">1969</option>

                    <option value="1968">1968</option>

                    <option value="1967">1967</option>

                    <option value="1966">1966</option>

                    <option value="1965">1965</option>

                    <option value="1964">1964</option>

                    <option value="1963">1963</option>

                    <option value="1962">1962</option>

                    <option value="1961">1961</option>

                    <option value="1960">1960</option>

                    <option value="1959">1959</option>

                    <option value="1958">1958</option>

                    <option value="1957">1957</option>

                    <option value="1956">1956</option>

                    <option value="1955">1955</option>

                    <option value="1954">1954</option>

                    <option value="1953">1953</option>

                    <option value="1952">1952</option>

                    <option value="1951">1951</option>

                    <option value="1950">1950</option>

                </select>

            </dd>

        </dl>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Preferences</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="color">Favorite Color:</label></dt>

            <dd>

                <input type="radio" name="color" id="colorBlue" value="Blue" /><label for="colorBlue" class="opt">Blue</label>

                <input type="radio" name="color" id="colorRed" value="Red" /><label for="colorRed" class="opt">Red</label>

                <input type="radio" name="color" id="colorGreen" value="Green" /><label for="colorGreen" class="opt">Green</label>

            </dd>

        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="interests">Interests:</label></dt>

            <dd>

                <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="interestsNews" value="News" /><label for="interestsNews" class="opt">News</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="interestsSports" value="Sports" /><label for="interestsSports" class="opt">Sports</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="interestsEntertainment" value="Entertainment" /><label for="interestsEntertainment" class="opt">Entertainment</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="interestsCars" value="Cars" /><label for="interestsCars" class="opt">Automotive</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="interestsTechnology" value="Technology" /><label for="interestsTechnology" class="opt">Technology</label>

            </dd>

        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="languages">Languages:</label></dt>

            <dd>

                <select size="4" name="languages[]" id="languages" multiple="multiple">


                </select>

            </dd>

        </dl>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Comments</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="comments">Message:</label></dt>

            <dd><textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea></dd>

        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="upload">Upload a File:</label></dt>

            <dd><input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" /></dd>

        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="test">Sample Button:</label></dt>

            <dd><button type="button" name="test" id="test">I Do Nothing</button></dd>

        </dl>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="action">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

    </fieldset>

</form>

<p id="footer">Niceforms v.2.0<br />&copy;Lucian Slatineanu - <a href="http://www.emblematiq.com/">Emblematiq</a><br />Last update: Nov 13 2008</p>

</div></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an external datasource pretty easily with jQuery. First you would need to setup a datasource. It could be an .asp page that draws information from a database, a text file, or really any other file you would like to use.

--Datasource Output (Maybe just a text file that looks like this)--

```
English,French,Spanish,Italian,Chinese,Japanese,Russian,Esperanto
```

--jQuery code--

```
$(function () {
    $.get('path_to/file.txt', function (data) {
        var output = data.split(','),
            tmp = '';
        for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            tmp += '<option value=' + output[i] + '>' + output[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#languages').html(tmp);
    });
});
```

The above code executes after the dom is ready (`$(function () {`) and uses an AJAX request. After the AJAX request comes back successful the data is split at the commas into an array, then that array is iterated through and a temporary variable (`tmp`) stores what you want to inject into the dom. After the `for(){}` loop runs the `tmp` variable is injected into the `id="languages"` select input.

Here is a link to the jQuery documentation for the `$.get()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: this is amazing how would i call this please in the code above?? thank you again!

Comment: can you show me please what changes i need to make to the code i posted above

Comment: You will need to change the `path_to/file.txt` to your datasource and then place the jQuery code into the source of the page with the `id="languages"` select input. The code will run itself once the dom is ready. And of course the JavaScript (jQuery) code must be placed within some `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: i did exactly what you said and it is not displaying anything in the list can you please check my code, i edited my question. thank you again for yoru help

Comment: My solution requires the jQuery library, add this to the header: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: i just included that and still same result, please see the edited code

Comment: Check your browser's error console for any JavaScript related errors. If you have a debugging console like FireBug for Firefox then you can add `console.log('log something');` to your code to track down the error. You can also use `alert('alert something');` if you do not have a debugging console. I tested the code in a jsfiddle and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/eMz9s/ (Note: I had to change the jsfiddle to have a hard-coded string to parse since I could not do an AJAX request from the jsfiddle)

Comment: thank you for your amazing help i will do exactly as you suggest and report back

Comment: i am getting from IE: line 15 object expected

Comment: @I__: This problem is usually solved on the **server side** (because some clients may not have javascript enabled). I presume that "niceforms" will degrade gracefully if there is no javascript (leaving plain form fields), but your dropdowns will remain empty.

Comment: @groo thank you for chiming in to help. yes niceforms will not work at all if javascript is not working; however niceforms works well but just not displaying the data from the txt file